# How to traverse li tags and collect their values with Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I wrote a tiny script to pull usernames from Github. I can get the first username's details out, but I don't understand how I can iterate through a list of elements with the same CSS selector class to put a list of the usernames together:

```
page = agent.get('https://github.com/angular/angular/stargazers')

html_results = Nokogiri::HTML(page.body)

first_username = html_results.at_css('.follow-list-name').text

first_username_location = html_results.at_css('.follow-list-info').text
```

Can you help me understand how I can iterate through all of the `follow-list-...` elements in the `page.body` and store the values in an array somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri `at_css` returns a **single** (first) match. Use `css` instead to get an **array** of matching results:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pp'

html = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://github.com/angular/angular/stargazers').read)

usernames = html.css('.follow-list-name').map(&:text)
locations = html.css('.follow-list-info').map(&:text)

pp usernames
pp locations
```

Output:

```
["Jeff Arese Vilar",
 "Yaroslav Dusaniuk",
 "Matthieu Le brazidec",
  ... ]

[" @Wallapop ",
 " Ukraine, Vinnytsia",
 " Joined on Jul 4, 2014",
 ... ]
```

Just note that to parse the rest of the members you will need to handle pagination. I.e. fetching the data from all the other pages with:

```
http://github.com/.../stargazers?page=NN
```

...where NN is the page number.

**Using the Github API**

A much more robust way is to use the Github Stargazers List API: 
https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#list-stargazers

Comment: Thank you Casper, much appreciated.

Comment: Said more correctly, `at_...` returns a Node and `css`, `xpath` or `search` return a NodeSet. A NodeSet acts a lot like an Array of Nodes.